# How to join tables in SQL Server such that join each row once

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, window-functions

I have two tables which are shown here:

[image: here]

I need to join them in some way to achieve this result set:

[image: here]

Is there any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You need to **explain** what your "logic" / intention is - just posting those tables doesn't really tell us what you're trying to do....

Comment: Start by naming your tables and explain what the different fields mean en what the relation is between wiich fields.For example: do rows that have the same date 'belong to each other' ? Do you want the rows that have the same amount to match up? So many questions... Explain what your reasoning is that leads from the two tables to the combined tabled.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please don't ask us  to do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows of each table for each date with `row_number()` and `full join` the results:

```
select 
    t1.prof, 
    t2.project, 
    coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) date,
    t1.amount amount1,
    t2.amount amount2
from (
    select 
        t1.*,
        row_number() over(partition by date order by prof) rn
    from table1 t1
) t1
full join (
    select 
        t2.*,
        row_number() over(partition by date order by project) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.rn = t2.rn
```